# Eliminate zero values and put values in two different columns in one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d36c040c667a974fd5ad813832562fd0)

```
CREATE TABLE check_inbound 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data_source VARCHAR,
    product VARCHAR,
    inbound_type VARCHAR,
    quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO check_inbound (data_source, product, inbound_type, quantity)
VALUES 
('data_source_01', 'product_a', 'type_01', '500'),
('data_source_01', 'product_a', 'type_02', '200'),
('data_source_01', 'product_b', 'type_01', '130'),
('data_source_01', 'product_b', 'type_02', '320'),
('data_source_01', 'product_c', 'type_01', '700'),
('data_source_01', 'product_c', 'type_02', '850'),

('data_source_02', 'product_a', 'type_01', '980'),
('data_source_02', 'product_a', 'type_02', '315'),
('data_source_02', 'product_b', 'type_01', '760'),
('data_source_02', 'product_b', 'type_02', '512'),
('data_source_02', 'product_c', 'type_01', '125'),
('data_source_02', 'product_c', 'type_02', '720');
```

Expected result:

| product | inbound_type | quantity_data_source_01 | quantity_data_source_02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product_a | type_01 | 500 | 980 |
| product_a | type_02 | 200 | 315 |
| product_b | type_01 | 130 | 760 |
| product_b | type_02 | 320 | 512 |
| product_c | type_01 | 700 | 125 |
| product_c | type_02 | 850 | 720 |

I want to compare the `quantity` per `product` and `inbound_type` in two different `data_sources`.

I was able to come close to the result with this query:

```
SELECT
    i.data_source AS date_source,
    i.product AS product,
    i.inbound_type AS inbound_type,
    (CASE WHEN i.data_source = 'data_source_01' THEN SUM(i.quantity) ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_data_source_01,
    (CASE WHEN i.data_source = 'data_source_02' THEN SUM(i.quantity) ELSE 0 END) AS quantity_data_source_02
FROM 
    check_inbound i
GROUP BY 
    1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 2,1
```

However, I could not figure out how I can get rid of the rows with the zero values and put the quantities on the same line as in the expected result.

Do you have any idea what I need to change to make it work?

Comment: A hint on test data. If you are trying to eliminate rows with zero values then you need to include some. And results to show what is expected. I.E. What happens when one source has zero values and the other does not. Also describe what you mean be *zero value*. A data point present with 0? A data point  with NULL? An expected data point that is missing? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a pivot query here, and should be aggregating only by product and type.  I suggest using `MAX` with `FILTER` here:

```sql
SELECT
    i.product AS product,
    i.inbound_type AS inbound_type,
    MAX(i.quantity) FILTER (WHERE i.data_source = 'data_source_01') AS quantity_data_source_01,
    MAX(i.quantity) FILTER (WHERE i.data_source = 'data_source_02') AS quantity_data_source_02
FROM check_inbound i
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

If you wanted to use `CASE` expressions, then use this version e.g.

```sql
MAX(CASE WHEN i.data_source = 'data_source_01'
         THEN i.quantity END) AS quantity_data_source_01
```